# Errors in created activity help (android)

Tags: java, android

I keep getting errors in code below, specifically the two pieces surrounded by asterisks (`R.id.action_settings` and `fragment_display_message`,)

```
package com.example.completelypointlessapp;

import android.app.Fragment;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivity;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class DisplayMessageActivity extends ActionBarActivity {

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        // Get the message from the intent
        Intent intent = getIntent();
        String message = intent.getStringExtra(MainActivity.EXTRA_MESSAGE);

        // Create the text view
        TextView textView = new TextView(this);
        textView.setTextSize(40);
        textView.setText(message);

        // Set the text view as the activity layout
        setContentView(textView);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
        // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
        // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
        int id = item.getItemId();
        if (id == **R.id.action_settings**) {
            return true;
        }
        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }

    /**
     * A placeholder fragment containing a simple view.
     */
    public static class PlaceholderFragment extends Fragment {

        public PlaceholderFragment() { }

        @Override
        public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
              Bundle savedInstanceState) {
              View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.**fragment_display_message,**
                      container, false);
              return rootView;
        }
    }
}
```

The errors state:"`fragment_display_message cannot be resolved or is not a field" and "action_settings cannot be resolved or is not a field`"

Can anyone help resolve this?
(Apology for certain incorrect formatting, I am new to this site)

Comment: `import com.example.completelypointlessapp.R;` in your `Activity`

Comment: That hasn't changed anything?

Comment: @CP then `clean and built` your project.......

Comment: I've cleaned it and it auto-builds, nothing changed

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_display_message,
                      container, false);
```

- Do you have `fragment_display_message.xml` layout file ?

> ```
> if (id == R.id.action_settings)
> ```

- Do you have the custom menu file for ActionBar ?

Example -

```
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" >
    <item
        android:id="@+id/action_settings"
        android:title="Settings"
        android:showAsAction="never"
        >
    </item>

</menu>
```

If answer to both is NO, then error is obvious.

Comment: I'm pretty much a beginner, how would I go about adding these files and where should I put them?

Comment: ActionBar is not a small thing and so is difficult to tell here. I recommend you read tutorial like http://www.grokkingandroid.com/adding-actionviews-to-your-actionbar/